# Ziparchive always includes parent directory

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to zip all files and folder within a folder
The structure looks like so:

```
storage/app/3
 - folder 1
   -file 1
   -file 2
 - folder 2
   -file 3
```

When I run the zip script I want the zip to be 3.zip with all the folders and files in the next level
However I always end up with:

```
3.zip
 - 3
   - folder 1
   -file 1
   -file 2
   - folder 2
   -file 3
```

Where I want:

```
 3.zip
   - folder 1
     -file 1
     -file 2
   - folder 2
     -file 3
```

The code works on my Linux servers, but on IIS and windows I get the additional level.

This is my code:

```
 $rootPath = public_path() .'/storage/app/' . $request->course_id . '/';        
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
 $zip->open(public_path() .'/storage/app/' . $request->course_id . '/' . $request->course_id . '.zip', (ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE));
    
  $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
                \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
            );
    
            
  foreach($files as $name => $file)  {  
    if (!$file->isDir() AND (strpos($name, $request->course_id.'.zip') === FALSE)){
      $zip->addFile($file, str_replace("C:\sites\cnnect-portal\public/storage/app/","", $file));
     } 
   }
```

I have tried to exclude the file from the loop by saying 'if $name == $request->course_id' skip this but that doesnt work because I dont see $name ever being just the folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will extracts the filename from the path.
`$zip->addFile($file,basename($file));`

And another guess would be that you need to include `course_id` here also:

```
  foreach($files as $name => $file)  {  
    if (!$file->isDir() AND (strpos($name, $request->course_id.'.zip') === FALSE)){
      $zip->addFile($file, str_replace("C:\sites\cnnect-portal\public/storage/app/3","", $file));
     } 
   }
```